# Hi i am trying to learn Apache camel framework. I dont know what i am doing wrong here

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

As far as i know you can create Camel Context inside configure method. So i am trying to print something on screen using this context. But its not working. i dont know what i am doing wrong here..

```
public class CamelApi extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new CamelApi());
        System.out.println("Hi Camel printing this");
        context.start();
        
    }    

}
```

Comment: I highly recommend to get the [Camel in Action book](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition). It explains the Camel framework concepts and basics first and continues then to the advanced topics.

Comment: Also take a look at some of the Camel examples, there are link from the Camel website

Answer (score 0):

When your Integrating Camel with Spring Boot, you don't actually need to add the(your) **RouteBuilder(CamelApi) Class** to **CamelContext** and then start the same. All you  need to is to run the Spring boot main class. In your case, if you just want to print and see something, you can do like below,

CamelApi.class

```
public class CamelApi extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Hi Camel printing this");

}}
```

Now just run the **Spring boot main class**, you can see the print statement in console.
(Once you get comfortable using camel and spring boot, start using **Logger class** instead of **System.out.println()** )

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or any issues similar to what you faced earlier

Comment: follow this link: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/bootcamel, this might help you